# Angular JS carousel not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with the following angular carousel [click here](http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/) my angular controller doesn't seem to be working which is calling out the images.[click here for my source code](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pNnkPOAlSGEzFdeMrZJ?p=preview) I have pretty followed the code demonstrated in the demo. However i am not having any joy getting my images to display. Can someone pin-point exactly where i am going wrong?

```
  <body np-app="myApp" ng-controller='demoController'>
<div>
    <ul data-rn-carousel rn-carousel-buffered rn-carousel-index="currentSport" class="image">
        <li ng-repeat="image in sportImages" style="background-image:url({{ image }});">
            <div class="layer" ng-bind-html-unsafe="image"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="currentSport = currentSport - 1" ng-disabled="currentSport == 0">prev</button>
    <button ng-click="currentSport = currentSport + 1" ng-disabled="currentSport == sportImages.length - 1">next</button>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You haven't shown your controller/app here or in Plunkr.

Comment: @JustinNiessner  http://plnkr.co/edit/3pNnkPOAlSGEzFdeMrZJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'data' infront of the rn-carousel directive.